# Grinder - JIRA tests fail

Tags: jira, grinder

I'm trying to run Atlassian's grinder test for JIRA as [described here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/ATLAS/JIRA+Performance+Testing+with+Grinder)

However the result from each test is something like below.

Searching has led me to believe that an error like this appears when some of the dashboards have been changed, but that is not my issue, as I have a new JIRA install with no dashboard changes.

Has anyone successfully gotten this suite of tests to work?

```
3/14/13 2:19:47 PM (thread 0 run 0 test 100): Aborted run due to Jython exception:
extraction pattern not matching:  
[title":"Introduction".*?renderedGadgetUrl":"http:\\/\\/.*?(\\/.*?)"] [calling TestRunner]
extraction pattern not matching: [title":"Introduction".*?renderedGadgetUrl":"http:\\/\\/.*?(\\/.*?)"]
    File "/home/users/smcconnell/grinder/jira-performance-tests/target/classes/test_scripts/./env.py", line 56, in extract
    File "/home/users/smcconnell/grinder/jira-performance-tests/target/classes/test_scripts/./dashboard.py", line 156, in notLoggedIn
    File "/home/users/smcconnell/grinder/jira-performance-tests/target/classes/test_scripts/./interactions.py", line 78, in goHome
    File "./agent_issue_browser.py", line 34, in __call__
3/14/13 2:19:49 PM (thread 0 run 1 test 100): Aborted run due to Jython exception: extraction pattern not matching: [title":"Introduction".*?renderedGadgetUrl":"http:\\/\\/.*?(\\/.*?)"] [calling TestRunner]
extraction pattern not matching: [title":"Introduction".*?renderedGadgetUrl":"http:\\/\\/.*?(\\/.*?)"]
    File "/home/users/smcconnell/grinder/jira-performance-tests/target/classes/test_scripts/./env.py", line 56, in extract
    File "/home/users/smcconnell/grinder/jira-performance-tests/target/classes/test_scripts/./dashboard.py", line 156, in notLoggedIn
    File "/home/users/smcconnell/grinder/jira-performance-tests/target/classes/test_scripts/./interactions.py", line 78, in goHome
    File "./agent_issue_browser.py", line 34, in __call__
```

Comment: Please post the grinder script along with the error that you have pasted. You are leaving us with our wild imagination on what could be wrong

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem.  The issue seemed to be that JIRA was configured with gzip compression on.  Once I turned off gzip compression on the "General Configuration" page, the tests started running.